# Find maximum likelihood for Poisson when $\theta_1 < \theta_2$

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, poisson-distribution, maximum-likelihood

The question is simple. We have two independent Poisson random variables. The parameters are $\theta_1, \theta_2$ respectively. We only have one single observation for both random variables. The general maximum likelihood without any restriction is $\frac{\theta_1^{x_1}}{x_1!} e^{-\theta_1}    \frac{\theta_2^{x_2}}{x_2!} e^{-\theta_2}$  and I can find the MLE is $\theta_1 = x_1, \theta_2 = x_2$.

But now the restriction is $\theta_1 \leq \theta_2$. I don't know how to get MLE in this case.

This is a necessary step before I construct the likelihood ratio test. So I need to know MLE under the case $\theta_1 < \theta_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_1 < x_2$ then you can just use the maximum likelihood estimators.

If $x_1 \geq x_2$ then this won't work. In this case we want the maximum likelihood estimators to be equal to each other. This way $x_2 \leq \hat{\theta}_1 \leq \hat{\theta}_2 \leq x_1$ with $\hat{\theta}_1, \hat{\theta}_2$ being as close as possible to their unconstrained maximum likelihood estimates.

If $x_1 \geq x_2$, we want $\hat{\theta}_1, \hat{\theta}_2$ to be as close as possible to their unconstrained maximum likelihood estimates as possible because the closer they are, the higher the likelihood. The plot below shows the likelihood $\theta_1^{x_1} e^{-\theta_1} /x_1!$ for $x_1 = 3$. As $\theta_1$ gets closer to $3$, the likelihood increases. If we leave a gap between $\hat{\theta}_1, \hat{\theta}_2$ then we know we're not maximizing the likelihood, since we can increase it by moving $\hat{\theta}_1$ closer to $x_1$ or moving $\hat{\theta}_2$ closer to $x_2$.
[image: Likelihood of one observation of 3 from Poisson]

Setting $\theta_1 = \theta_2$ we have likelihood
$$\frac{\theta_1^{x_1+x_2}}{x_1!x_2!} e^{2\theta_1},$$
which is maximized when $$\theta_1 = \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}.$$

So in the case $x_1 \geq x_2$, use $$\hat{\theta}_1 = \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}, \hat{\theta}_2 = \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}.$$

Comment: Sorry, it should not be strict inequality. I changed my question. Thanks!

Comment: But I am still not fully convinced by why we need to equate $x_1$ and $x_2$ to get MLE in the second case.

Comment: Thanks, I've dropped the strict inequality bit and hopefully explained better why you want the estimators to be equal in the second case